# Importar datos CSV a R en MAC

Tags: r, macos

Hola buenas tardes alguien sabe como importar de manera correcta los csv a Rstudio en mac? Yo normalmente uso las funciones read.csv & read.csv2 pero cuando lo hago en imac a veces las tildes y las ñ las cambia por codigo como Aos_Experiencia = Años de experiencia lo cual me dificulta porque no se puede trabajar así...

PD: Tengo la mac configurada en español "es_ES.UTF-8"

Comment: Bienvenido RodrigoAIns a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0):

Para importar caracteres como la ñ debes indicar que la codificación la haga en utf-8.

prueba algo así:

```
mi_fichero <- read.csv("./datos.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

Espero te sirva.
Saludos!